# intermittent ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-spark, oozie

Seeing odd behaviour when running spark app, both using spark-submit, oozie workflow and oozie coordinator. I'm intermittently getting failure with:

`ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.

So in a workflow it may run or it may fail, in a coordinator, same job running multiple times, it can go through twice and fail once. Pretty random.

No idea what to make of this, don't even know where to start from. So any suggestion is appreciated.

Just to mention, all my Maven dependencies are scoped "provided".

_SD

Comment: Maybe one or more nodes in your cluster have outdated dependency jars, and the tasks that have a misfortune to be randomly distributed to the executors running on those nodes are failing?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Do you think there's a way to confirm this hypothesis?